# Standard permissions for wordpress; Plugin installation asks for FTP credentials

Tags: plugins, permissions, filesystem, ftp

I'm on a server that does not have FTP installed and will not have FTP installed. I have another website that I've been able to install plugins in before, including the one I'm trying to install now (WP-PageNavi).

Does anyone have a list of standard permissions for WordPress that they use themselves so that they don't run into this issue?

I've read the [WordPress article](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions) on the topic and looked at other questions on this website.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is your host?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Standard permissions for most WordPress installations is 755 for directories and 644 for files.

For media uploads, auto plugin installation and updates the directories need to be owned by the same user PHP is running under. Usually this is nobody:nobody or www-data:www-data.

Comment: The www-data:www-data worked. I'm not sure why though because I have other websites on the same server that did not require this. Either way, thanks!

Comment: Why is that? If it's group writable, why does it have to be owned by Apache2?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the web files are owned by the apache webserver user (on Ubuntu it's "www-data"). Check this by doing a:

```
ls -al
```

And if they are not, set them using:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data folder/
```